# exsheets varying of question's point value

Tags: exsheets

I'm using [exsheets package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets). I want variations with different point values.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[load-headings,load-tasks,]{exsheets}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-example.inc}
    \begin{question}{2}
        What is the result of \vary{$2+3$}{$1231+4431$}?
    \end{question}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
%
%
\SetVariations{2}
\variant{1}
\section{Group A}
\includequestions{\jobname-example.inc}
\newpage
\variant{2}
\section{Group B}
\includequestions{\jobname-example.inc}
\end{document}
```

I want two different point value:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[load-headings,load-tasks,]{exsheets}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-example.inc}
    \begin{question}{\vary{2}{4}} % <<<==== CHANGE =======
        What is the result of \vary{$2+3$}{$1231+4431$}?
    \end{question}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
%
%
\SetVariations{2}
\variant{1}
\section{Group A}
\includequestions{\jobname-example.inc}
\newpage
\variant{2}
\section{Group B}
\includequestions{\jobname-example.inc}
\end{document}
```

But it fails on changed line:

```
! You can't use `\long' after \the.
```

Is there any solutions without create two *full* question (the differences between questions only the numbers)?

Comment: That's not possible with the current implementation. I'll add something to the next release and will write an answer then

Comment: Oh, understand. Many-many thanks for your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v0.12 `exsheets` provides a possibility: a leading bang in the points argument to the `question` environment prevents parsing of the points:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetVariations{2}

\begin{document}

\variant{1}
\section{Group A}
\begin{question}{!\vary{2}{4}}
  What is the result of \vary{$2+3$}{$1231+4431$}?
\end{question}

\variant{2}\setcounter{question}{0}
\section{Group B}
\begin{question}{!\vary{2}{4}}
  What is the result of \vary{$2+3$}{$1231+4431$}?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This comes with a cost: the points are not added to the sum of points any more. Should that be needed one could define something like

```
\newcommand*\varypoints[2]{%
  % \addpoints*{} only adds the points to the sum
  % \points*{} only prints them (without `unit')
  \vary
    {\addpoints*{#1}\points*{#1}}
    {\addpoints*{#2}\points*{#2}}%
}
```

and use it instead. (However, for the example this would sum both points from group A *and* group B – surely not what's wanted.

The easiest but maybe not safest way would be to define

```
\newcommand*\varypoints[2]{%
  % \addpoints*{} only adds the points to the sum
  % \points*{} only prints them (without `unit')
  \vary
    {\addpoints*{#1}\points*{#1}}
    {}%
}
```

and swap arguments between compilations...

Comment: Wow! Great work! Now we have summer vacation but I'll try it! Thanks again!

Comment: @uzsolt You're welcome! If you like the answer you can thank be by upvoting :)

Comment: Ooops, I've accepted but didn't upvote.